# SCNNode orientation instead of eulerAngles

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I am trying to rotate `SCNNode` with `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` and changing of `eulerAngles`. I switch between rotation around `y` and around `z` axis. When I rotate only one of them everything is fine. But problem appears when I rotate both. It no longer rotate around axis itself but it rotates randomly.

I have read many answers especially from ARGeo like this one: [SCNNode Z-rotation axis stays constant, while X and Y axes change when node is rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997832/scnnode-z-rotation-axis-stays-constant-while-x-and-y-axes-change-when-node-is-r) , and I understand problem of `eulerAngles` and gimbal lock.

But I don't understand how to correctly use `orientation` ant that `w` component. Is here someone who successfully used `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` and `orientation` instead of `eulerAngles`?

Comment: Found it on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one of an examples how to implement `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`.

I copied it from [How can I rotate an SCNNode....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48530159/how-can-i-rotate-an-scnnode-on-the-axis-the-camera-is-looking-down) SO post.

```
private var startingOrientation = GLKQuaternion.identity
private var rotationAxis = GLKVector3Make(0, 0, 0)

@objc private func handleRotation(_ rotation: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let node = sceneView.hitTest(rotation.location(in: sceneView), options: nil).first?.node else {
        return
    }
    if rotation.state == .began {
        startingOrientation = GLKQuaternion(boxNode.orientation)
        let cameraLookingDirection = sceneView.pointOfView!.parentFront
        let cameraLookingDirectionInTargetNodesReference = boxNode.convertVector(cameraLookingDirection,                                                                        
                                                                                 from: sceneView.pointOfView!.parent!)
        rotationAxis = GLKVector3(cameraLookingDirectionInTargetNodesReference)
    } else if rotation.state == .ended {
        startingOrientation = GLKQuaternionIdentity
        rotationAxis = GLKVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
    } else if rotation.state == .changed {
        let quaternion = GLKQuaternion(angle: Float(rotation.rotation), axis: rotationAxis)
        node.orientation = SCNQuaternion((startingOrientation * quaternion).normalized())
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for quick answer, since I switch rotating axis with button crucial for me was question from your link, I never realised from documentation that it could be as easy as SCNQuaternion(0, 0, 1, newRotation) to rotate it in z axis and SCNQuaternion(0, 1, 0, newOrientation) to rotate it on y axis ... Thank you!